# The access_token invalid

Tags: java, oltu

I get an issue from `oltu(version 0.31)`. I can get code and `access_token` successfully. But, if I access protect resource, the error said: `invalid access token`. when I print `resourceResponse.getBody()` still said invalid access token. If change to `httpclient` or `httpURLConnection` all is fine. Would you please tell me what am I wrong in my code

```
    public String getUserInfo(String accessToken) throws OAuthSystemException, OAuthProblemException {

    System.out.println("Get User info access Token: " + accessToken);

    OAuthClient oAuthClient = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());
    System.out.println("111111111111111111111");
    OAuthClientRequest bearerClientRequest = new OAuthBearerClientRequest(OauthConfig.userInfo).setAccessToken(accessToken).buildQueryMessage();
    System.out.println("22222222222222222222222");
    OAuthResourceResponse resourceResponse = oAuthClient.resource(bearerClientRequest, OAuth.HttpMethod.GET, OAuthResourceResponse.class);
    System.out.println("3333333333333333333333333");
    System.out.println(resourceResponse.getBody());

    return resourceResponse.getBody();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed this question. I found issue. my server access Token name is "accessToken", but oltu default name is "access_token". So, need to inheritance the OAuthBearerClientRequest and re-code all method.